# Very slow scanning process at large and legacy java project

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, legacy

Hi i´m working with a big and legacy product, and i have some performance issues when i run my sonar scanner.

Product:

- More than 600k loc
- More than 8k vulnerabilities
- 2k bugs
- 100k code smells
- More than 4k classes
- Duplication 12%
- A lot of cyclomatic complexity and cognitive issues

I know that are some Rules that causes more slow than others.
But i don´t know how to find out which are these slowest rules.

Relevant properties:

- Java source and target version is 1.6
- Maven wrapper 3.6.1
- Maven compiler plugin 3.6.0
- Maven surefire plugin 2.22.2
- Sonar maven plugin 3.6.1.1688
- Sonar server is 6.7

Some of my properties:

```
<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
<sonar.java.source>1.6</sonar.java.source>
```

Analysis report generated dir size=107 MB

Slowest steps:

```
Java Main Files AST scan
Sensor JavaSquidSensor
```

```
sh “export MAVEN_OPTS=’-Xms1512m -Xmx8096m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m’ ;” +" ./mvnw sonar:sonar -T 4 -X"
```

It tooks 09:30 hours to run sonar.
00:30 is about sending the scanner results to server and 9 hours is about running the scanner.

Comment: What exactly do you want help with? Do you want us to look into the issue of your code being too large in size? Or is there another issue you want to ask us?

Comment: Do you really need to run sonar 8 GiB memory? Furthermore the option `-T 4` will not work related to Sonar and will not really help apart from that to make a sonar analysis you have to do it `mvn clean verify sonar:sonar` apart from all previous how  long does a usual build via `mvn clean verify` take? Do you have integration tests running? 9:30 hours is extreme large value for that small code base?

Comment: @RemcoBuddelmeijer that's not a helpful comment. Over 9 hours is excessive for a project of that size which is what the question is about. Annoyingly there are no helpful answers here.